# How can i check if a URL is accessible to a user?

Tags: javascript, browser, server

Is there a way to check whether a website is accessible to a user?

The end user uses a web app which is stored on my server. Inside my app, there is a button they can click to navigate to a specific URL. I want to check whether the user can access the URL, else, I want to direct them to a different URL. I use the check below:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'https://example.com',
  success: function(data){
  console.log('there is a connection');
  }
});
```

The code above works as usual, however, the problem is that this code will ALWAYS be successful because it is executed on the server and the server has access to the website. I want this code to validate whether the user's machine and their network can specifically access a certain URL. Is this achievable?

Thanks.

Note: The user has a restricted network in which they can only access my app and a few other links.

The user will be using the Chrome browser.

Let me know if more clarification is needed.

Comment: use ping via cmd

Comment: whent the url was not accessible handle it with error:function(){}

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'https://example.com',
  success: function(data){
    alert("there is a connection");
  },
  error: function(data){
    window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/q/49376615/3890673';
  }
});
```